# Как запретить AUTO_INCREMENT при неудачной вставке

Tags: sql, mysql

При вставке очередной записи в таблицу, по определенным причинам она может не вставиться (например на колонке стоит ограничение уникальности и данный запрос его нарушает) но тем не менее колонка `id` в которой установлено свойство AUTO_INCREMENT увеличивается. Можно ли как-то это поведения изменить?

Comment: Можно, но не нужно. Или Вы, когда запись будете удалять, также захотите поправить индексы?

Comment: Насколько знаю, это особенность движка. Но разве это настолько критично?

Comment: Ну при удалении это одно, а при вставке зачем эти пропуски? Или всё таки не нужно так делать?

Comment: не нужно переживать по поводу индексов. Это личное дело движка. Если эти индексы влияют на отображение данных - тогда Вы что то делаете не так.

Comment: @Jeremen1, это разве может навредить хоть чему-то, кроме перфекционизма?

Comment: @Fike, бывает ещё переполнение, особенно если "неправильных" вставок неск сотен/тысяч в секунду (наверное это ошибка ахитектуры, но  тем не менее, бывает, что полагаются на ключи и только на них при вставке)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Не стоит использовать значения, сгенерированные механизмом AUTO_INCREMENT, для создания неразрывных последовательностей. Его основная задача - создания уникальных значений. Разрывы в последовательностях сгенерированных чисел является штатной ситуацией. Более того, она необходима для целостности базы данных.

Например, если у вас есть таблица статей с AUTO_INCREMENT-идентификаторами. Такой идентификатор часто используется в ссылке на статью. Если вы удалите статью, произойдет разрыв последовательности. Заполнять эту последовательность нельзя ни в коем случае, даже если вы убрали все ссылки на нее в пределах базы данных, на старую статью могут быт ссылки из сети Интернет. Поэтому старые статьи будут вести на страницу с новым текстом, что приведет к нарушению целостности данных.

Этот пример не совсем в контексте вашего вопроса, однако, создавая механизмы обхода разрывов в AUTO_INCREMENT, вы двигаетесь в сторону нарушения целостности данных. В большой системе отслеживать ошибки будет очень трудно. Для надежности будущей системы, лучше принять AUTO_INCREMENT как есть: разрыв - значит разрыв. Если система вырастет до больших объемов поддерживать ее будет проще и дешевле.

Если же вам требуется неразрывная нумерация статей, лучше для этого предусмотреть отдельное поле, не завязанное на механизм AUTO_INCREMENT - у него другие задачи.