# PostgreSQL: почему увеличивается sequence после ошибки?

Tags: postgresql

Здравствуйте. После неудачного запроса в базу данных, счетчик автоинкремента увеличивается, хотя запрос не выполнен. Почему так происходит и как возможно исправить без рутинных функции и прочего?
Например, дубликат при вставке

> DETAIL: Ключ "(name)=(ozornick)" уже существует

Но следующий INSERT пойдет не по порядку, а с учетом неудачных вставок

Comment: Почему - лучше у разработчиков узнайте. думаю что для упрощения поддержания уникальности id заранее резервируются. Как бороться: с этим не надо бороться. Архитектура БД должна быть выбрана так, что бы порядок и последовательность выдачи id не имела никакого значения

Comment: Я понял, что заранее резервирует. но запрос же не состоялся зачем обновлять этот самый резерв? Тот же mysql не добавляет свой auto increment (да, я догадываюсь, что там другая система)

Comment: MySQL не добавляет, ага, щаз. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/293150/    На самом деле такая проблема есть практически во всех БД. Тут вопрос в паралелльном доступе. Процесс А собирается вставить запись и получает ID. получил, атомарно. В это время процесс Б то же вставляет запись. получил ID. Процесс А наконец переходит к вставке, что то идет не так, он откатывает изменение. Но откатывать ID нельзя потому что Б уже взял следующий номер. Исправить это можно только заблокировав все вставки в таблицу пока транзакция А не завершена. На такое ни одна СУБД не пойдет

Comment: Вот это поворот) Тут поразмыслил, почему я так заблуждался, в предыдущих вариантах кода проводятся проверки на уникальность, поэтому незаметно все это. Ответом будем считать - проверять все данные перед вставкой...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как выяснилось **проще и разумнее проверять данные перед вставкой**, чем бороться с особенностями системы.